# Lubuntu 13.04 How to install entire repo?

Tags: apt, lubuntu, repository

I would like to install an entire repo, instead of going through and installing each package, is that possible?? Id think it be something like apt-get install repo-blahblahblah or something like that.

Comment: What? Are you kidding me? That's 30000+ packages and 50+ GB further. It's also not possible to install *all* packages as some conflict with others by design so the user makes a choice: e.g. Postfix vs Exim, kernel images, etc. And I don't want to know how your application menu looks like then... It will be HUGE.

Comment: I'm not trying to install 30,000+ packages, the repo I'm installing from is maybe 50-60 packages.

Comment: Okay, in that case I can provide an answer.

Answer (score 0):

That is certainly possible, but then the repo owner should provide a meta package which lists all the other packages as requirements. I don't think there's any command that performs `apt-get install *` as doing so would hardly ever make any kind of sense. The ubuntu-desktop package is a meta package that does nothing except list other packages to install. If it makes sense to install the entire repo in your case, I'd look for that kind of package.

Answer (score 0):

#### Use the `Origin` flag on packages

1. Locate the raw repository release file of the repository concerned in `/var/lib/apt/lists`, e.g. `dl.google.com_linux_chrome_deb_dists_stable_Release`.
2. Use `less` or `grep` to find the `Origin:` line:

   ```
   grep ^Origin\: /var/lib/apt/lists/dl.google.com_linux_chrome_deb_dists_stable_Release
   ```

   For me this outputs: `Origin: Google, Inc.`
3. Install [aptitude [image: Install aptitude]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/aptitude), a package manager.
4. Using the `Origin` found earlier we can query for packages in aptitude:

   ```
   aptitude search '~O "Google, Inc."'
   ```

   Try to narrow down the search pattern if there's more than you expected. See the [aptitude manual on search patterns](http://algebraicthunk.net/~dburrows/projects/aptitude/doc/en/ch02s03.html) for that.
5. If you like the results, install it:

   ```
   sudo aptitude install '~O "Google, Inc."'
   ```

#### Notes

- This does not take care about multiarch. The query above tries to install both `i386` and `amd64` packages.
- I agree with [Jo-Erlend Schinstad](https://askubuntu.com/a/320478/88802) that you *should* use a metapackage to install a group of packages. This depends on the repository maintainer of course, so it may not be available for all.
- You can also use GUI package managers for an easier way to accomplish the above. See [my other answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/320575/88802) to do so.

Answer (score 0):

I like to use [muon [image: Install muon]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/muon) for this, but you can probably accomplish the same using Synaptic.

1. Open Muon.
2. Filter by Origin (as shown in the screenshot).

   [image]
3. Select all packages in the results.
4. Right-click, hit *Mark for Installation*
5. Click *Apply Changes* in the toolbar.